# How to retrieve text from RichTextBlock in WinRT

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using the standard RichTextColumns.cs helper class that is added by VS2012's default Metro Style project template. It uses the RichTextBlock internally to add RichTextColumns. DataBinding is working fine with the following markup

```
<common:RichTextColumns>
 <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="400" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
 <RichTextBlock Width="400">
  <Paragraph>
   <Run Text="{Binding Content}"/>
  </Paragraph>
 </RichTextBlock>
```

Now I have the embedded hyperlinks in 'Content' that are not treated as hyperlinks in WinRT. I need them to behave like hyperlinks. So I want to retrieve the text that's getting bound to the RichTextBlock, tokenize it, insert InlineUI elements that have the HyperlinkButton at appropriate places. Now I could do all this if I could only retrieve the text that is getting bound to the RichTextBlock. Unfortunately I can't seem to 'retrieve' it.

I tried

```
RichTextBlock value = (RichTextBlock)GetValue(RichTextContentProperty);
valueRun = (Run)((Paragraph)value.Blocks[0]).Inlines[0];
value.Select(((Paragraph)value.Blocks[0]).ContentStart, ((Paragraph)value.Blocks[0]).ContentEnd);
Paragraph para = TokenizeTweet(value.SelectedText);
```

But the SelectedText is always empty.
However if I do a 
`value.Blocks.Clear()`
it clears out the text that is getting bound. What am I missing?

Simply put, how to retrieve unformatted text from a RichTextBlock in WinRT (Not WPF or Silverlight).

Thanks and Regards,
Sumit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to retrieve it, why not simply use a converter on the binding?

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Sounds like the right approach. Will get back with results shortly.

Comment: Okay, just a Converter was not able to cut it because I needed to add various types of 'View' elements dynamically. So I ended up creating a custom DataTemplateSelector based on the sample here http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/05/22/Using-Dynamic-XAML-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx . I am able to generate the entire template and get it bound to the required data. I had to make some sacrifices like adding a new View Model collection property called Contents so that binding with ListItem works. It's hackish, but it works for now. The upvote stays because it 'nudged' me into thinking differently.